# Java applet works in IDE, but not in browser

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, applet

So I created a simple game that was working not too long ago. Recently, though, when I try to run it in any browser it just gives me a NullPointerException. The thread stack is as follows:

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@18a270a
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.
security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss,com.sun.browser,com.sun.glass,com.sun.javafx,com.sun.media.jfxmedia,com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl,com.sun.openpisces,com.sun.prism,com.sun.scenario,com.sun.t2k,com.sun.webpane,com.sun.pisces,com.sun.webkit
security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.regexp.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.extensions.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.templates.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.cmdline.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.util.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.res.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.,com.sun.org.glassfish.,org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.,com.sun.java.accessibility.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss,com.sun.browser,com.sun.glass,com.sun.javafx,com.sun.media.jfxmedia,com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl,com.sun.openpisces,com.sun.prism,com.sun.scenario,com.sun.t2k,com.sun.webpane,com.sun.pisces,com.sun.webkit
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@13b7c28
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:////files5.ad.lake.stark.k12.oh.us/shd/2015/15TROYERJONATHAN/Documents/Computer%20Science/Game/GUI.class, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:////files5.ad.lake.stark.k12.oh.us/shd/2015/15TROYERJONATHAN/Documents/Computer%20Science/Game/, version: null]
security: Accessing keys and certificate in Mozilla user profile: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
security: SSV validation: running: 1.7.0_25, requested: null, range: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.25
security: continue with running version
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:////files5.ad.lake.stark.k12.oh.us/shd/2015/15TROYERJONATHAN/Documents/Computer%20Science/Game/ColorPanel.class, version: null]
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 216867 us, pluginInit dt 217500 us, TotalTime: 434367 us
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GUI.init(GUI.java:70)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@13b7c28
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

Here's where the error is (at least as far as I can tell):

```
URL url=getCodeBase();
String u=url.toString();
```

The applet works fine when it is run in JCreator, but not in any browser or Adobe Dreamweaver. What does the thread stack mean?

Comment: This is the thread dump, which is different from the stack trace you get when the exception occurs. You should post the stack trace.

Comment: I just uploaded the stack trace, you should be able to figure stuff out now.

Comment: where is the stack trace ? and if your code is too long then just post the part that causes the NPE

Comment: OKAY, I think I (finally) figured it out. The real problem here is that I'm not a professional programmer, I'm just a high-schooler and have no idea about the specific ins and outs of Java. So if someone could tell me what is wrong **specifically** and **in a way I can understand**, that would be nice.

Comment: @MalcolmSmith isn't the stacktrace present in the dump (the NullPointerException at the bottom)?

Comment: @C.Champagne yep, it is now. When I added that comment a thread dump had been posted, we now have the console output including the stacktrack.

Comment: @Spidermaninja you can use http://pastebin.com/ if you want to avoid emailing and have a look there to have an explaination about the stacktrace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `GUI` is the the name of the class of your applet. (BTW, it should be nice if you had defined its [package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) but it has not impact on this issue)

From the stacktrace in the traces you transmitted, I can also suppose that the two lines of code you put in your question are line 69 and 70.

I can thus suppose that `getCodeBase()` returns `null` so that the following line automatically leads to a `NullPointerException` (NPE). [Starting from Java 7 update 25, `getCodeBase()` returns null when the applet is running from the local file system.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u25-relnotes-1955741.html)

You should thus check if the value returned by getCodeBase() is null so your code could look like the following:

```
String u = "Some default value";
URL url=getCodeBase();
if(url != null) {
    u=url.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to circumvent this? I know that getDocumentBase() is also returning null as well, but there should be _some_ way to access my files.

Comment: @Spidermaninja This could be the object of an another question! The problem is that I don't know exactly what you need. Anyway, it seems that the URL you enter to access your webpage is something like file:////my_resource_path....which is a file path and can be considered as local. You should certainly use a real web server and access it with an HTTP address.